# How to select and highlight a row in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

With a datatable that has a column as hyperlink, is it possible to select the whole row?
If so, how can we select and highlight so user can see the row is selected?

Comment: are you talking about gridview? DataTable is just a container which stores the data.

Comment: if you are talking about gridview try see about [GridView.SelectedRowStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) else please concrete what is DataTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about gridview try see about [GridView.SelectedRowStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
you can try it like this

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
   ...
   autogenerateselectbutton="True"
   selectedindex="1"
   ...       >

     <Columns>
         ...
     </Columns>

   <selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightCyan"
     forecolor="DarkBlue"
     font-bold="true"/>  
 </asp:gridview>
```

or if you have special css class for selected row

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
   ...
   autogenerateselectbutton="True"
   selectedindex="1"
   ...       >

     <Columns>
         ...
     </Columns>

   <selectedrowstyle CssClass="YouCssClassForSelectedRow"/>         
 </asp:gridview>
```